# R: efficient way to create a similarity matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, similarity

So I have a huge matrix of data and would like to create a similarity matrix. I know there are different functions to use (correlation, cosine, mutual information and etc), but my question is about the efficient implementation. For example may be getting advantage of data.frame,

so here is a sample code so far, where I only calculate the similarity for half of the matrix,

```
#rm(list = ls())

load(iris)# the real data is 15K*300
tt = iris[c(1:5),1:4]

similarity_matrix_cor = matrix(data = 0, nrow = nrow(tt), ncol = nrow(tt))

for (cnt.1 in 1:nrow(tt))
{   
    print(cnt.1)
    for (cnt.2 in cnt.1:nrow(tt))
    {
        similarity_matrix_cor[cnt.1, cnt.2] = cor(as.numeric(tt[cnt.1,]), as.numeric(tt[cnt.2,]))
    }

}

complete_mat = function(tt) # eventually I add the other half of the matrix
{
    return(t(tt) + tt - diag(diag(tt),nrow=nrow(tt),ncol=ncol(tt)))
}

matrix_cor = complete_mat(similarity_matrix_cor)
```

Comment: You realise that `cor` takes a matrix as input....?

Comment: oh, yes; practically, I am using another similarity method (mutual information). I just wanted to make it as simple as possible. my MI measurement is a function that I have written.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
#helper function to access row pairs
matab<-Vectorize(
    function(a,b,fun,data) {
        fun(data[a,],data[b,])
    }, vectorize.args=list("a","b")
)
```

and then use `outer()` to create all paris

```
outer(1:nrow(x),1:nrow(x),matab,fun=cor,data=as.matrix(x))
```

just replace `fun=cor` with what ever function you like. It will receive pairs of rows of your data as input. This solution does not assume that your function is symmetric so the result of `fun(a,b)` could be different than `fun(b,a)`